# Asyncio server stops to respond after the first request

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write an asyncio-based server. The problem is, that it stops to respond after the first request.

My code is built upon [this template for echo-server](https://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tcp_echo.html)  and [this method to pass parameters to coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678184/how-to-pass-additional-parameters-to-handle-client-coroutine).

```
class MsgHandler:

    def __init__(self, mem):
        # here (mem:dict) I store received metrics
        self.mem = mem

    async def handle(self, reader, writer):
        #this coroutine handles requests
        data = await reader.read(1024)
        print('request:', data.decode('utf-8'))
        # read_msg returns an answer based on the request received
        # My server closes connection on every second request
        # For the first one, everything works as intended,
        # so I don't thik the problem is in read_msg()
        response = read_msg(data.decode('utf-8'), self.mem)
        print('response:', response)
        writer.write(response.encode('utf-8'))
        await writer.drain()
        writer.close()


def run_server(host, port):
    mem = {}
    msg_handler = MsgHandler(mem)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = asyncio.start_server(msg_handler.handle, host, port, loop=loop)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    server.close()
    loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
    loop.close()
```

On the client-side I either get an empty response or ConnectionResetError (104, 'Connection reset by peer').

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. Could you please share your response example, or make the example code runnable and reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the writer with `writer.close()` in the handler, which closes the socket.

From the 3.9 docs on `StreamWriter`:

[image]

Also, if you don't close the stream writer, then you would still have store it somewhere in order to keep receiving messages over that same connection.