# Python how to use await in a lambda

Tags: python, lambda, async-await, python-asyncio

I want to use 'await' for the lambda function as shown below.

```
self.voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('music.mp3'), after=lambda e: await self.test(x))

SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
```

How can I fix it to make it feel like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I only use the await keyword inside of async function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027030/why-can-i-only-use-the-await-keyword-inside-of-async-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answer said, you can't put `await` in a `lambda`. But if `await` is the outermost operator in the expression, you can omit both the async and await and have the lambda directly return the awaitable:

```
self.voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('music.mp3'),
                        after=lambda e: self.test(x))
```

Without the `await`, the lambda simply returns `self.test(x)`. As that value was to be awaited, `self.test(x)` must obviously return an awaitable object. This awaitable object will be received by code that at some point invokes `o.after(e)` and awaits the result. In other words, `await o.after(e)` will be equivalent to `await self.test(x)`, which is what you wanted to accomplish.

In general, an `async def` function:

```
async def foo():
    return await bar()
```

can be replaced with:

```
def foo():
    return bar()
```

Although `foo()` is not async in the latter case, the end result is the same: `await foo()` will return the result of awaiting `bar()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50683084/1600898) for another example.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to make a lambda async, but you can do something like:

```
async def temp():
    await self.test(x)

self.voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('music.mp3'), after = temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've read the posts at the top and I did say the most recent one won't work but I don't know about the other one. But here is a easier solution to this.
First off, `await` cannot be within a lambda expression since it isn't asyncable. Secondly, I am wondering why they're `self.voice_channel` and `self.test`. If you have the voice_channel already within the function the self needs to be omitted. Thirdly, this is my preference but add the source as a variable.

Here is my solution to this:

```py
source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('music.mp3')
voice_channel.play(source, after=lambda e: asyncio.run(test(x)))
```

Be sure to add in the asyncio import all the way at the top:

```
import asyncio
```

Code is shorten and workable.